# Selecting href attributers with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, dom, puppeteer

I am trying to extract a few `urls` from [this](https://divisare.com/) page with Puppeteer.

However all my script is returning is `undefined`

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function run() {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://divisare.com/');


    let projects = await page.evaluate((sel) => {

        return document.getElementsByClassName(sel)
    }, 'homepage-project-image');


    var aNode = projects[0].href;

    console.log(aNode);
    console.log(projects.length)



  browser.close();

}
run();
```

However when I run something like the below I am at least able to get the proper count of the links I am trying to extract.

```
let projects = await page.evaluate((sel) => {

    return document.getElementsByClassName(sel).length
}, 'homepage-project-image');


console.log(projects);
```

Am I trying to access my `projects` `HTMLCollection` incorrectly? What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puppeteer cannot return non-serialisable value from `evaluate` statement (see [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2418) and the following [PR](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/pull/2425))

One way to solve this would be:

```
let projects = await page.evaluate((sel) => {

        return document.getElementsByClassName(sel)[0].href;
    }, 'homepage-project-image');
```

Remember that `document.getElementsByClassName` returns `HTMLCollection`, so if you want to iterate over the results you need something like:

```
 let projects = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
            return Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(sel)).map(node => node.href);
        }, 'homepage-project-image');
```