# Puppeter - Link inside an iFrame

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have to get the advertising link below the bullet points of [this page](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07DDDB34D).

I am trying with Puppeter but I am having trouble because the Ad is an iframe!

I can successfully get what I need using Chrome console:

```
document.querySelector('#adContainer a').href
```

**Puppetter**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setViewport({width: 1440, height: 1000})
  await page.goto('https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07DDDB34D', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})

  await page.waitFor(2500);

  const elementHandle = await page.$eval('#adContainer a', el => el.href);

  console.log(elementHandle);
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png', fullPage: false});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

**Error: Error: failed to find element matching selector "#adContainer a"**

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setViewport({width: 1440, height: 1000})
  await page.goto('https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07DDDB34D', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})

const adFrame = page.frames().find(frame => frame.name().includes('"adServer":"cs'))
const urlSelector = '#sp_hqp_shared_inner > div > a';
const url = await adFrame.$eval(urlSelector, element => element.textContent);
console.log(url);


  await browser.close();
```

**Run**: https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/

Comment: The reason that works in chrome console is because you switched to the iframe context when you inspected it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do that query inside the frame itself, which can be accessed via [page.frames()](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.11.0&show=api-pageframes):

```
const adFrame = page.frames().find(frame => frame.name().includes('<some text only appearing in name of this iFrame>');
const urlSelector = '#sp_hqp_shared_inner > div > a';
const url = await adFrame.$eval(urlSelector, element => element.textContent);
console.log(url);
```

How I got the selector of that url:
[image]

**Discaimer**
I haven't tried this myself. Also, I think the appropriate way to get that url inside the iFrame is something more like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50151310/772985):

```
const url = await adFrame.evaluate((sel) => {
  return document.querySelectorAll(sel)[0].href;
}, urlSelector);
```

Comment: `frame.name().includes('"adServer":"cs')` isn't specific enough, as there appear to 4 other instances with that match according to Chrome Dev tools search. However, it looks like (at least for me), it has an id of `ape_detail_hero-quick-promo_desktop_iframe` - https://imgur.com/a/JTOMiiM - can you confirm same for you?

Comment: Thank you. I tried to run it but it doesn't fetch the url. If I print the html content of frame i noticed the url is not there. I updated the question (Edit section) where you can re-test it using https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch to the frame you want to work on every time the page loads.

```
async getRequiredLink() {
    return await this.page.evaluate(() => {
        let iframe = document.getElementById('frame_id'); //pass id of your frame
        let doc = iframe.contentDocument; // changing the context to the working frame
        let ele = doc.querySelector('you-selector'); // selecting the required element
        return ele.href;
    });
}
```